# How to Use Conditional Formatting To Change a cells color once it gets closer to another cells number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I'm trying to figure out how to create a formula that changes the background cell on LAST to a different color once it gets 5 points closer to the MACRO PIVOT number cell. Im trying to systematize my trading.

For Example: TSLA LAST: 683.8/ MACRO PIVOT is 718 but how can I get the LAST number background to change to a bright green once it reaches 713

[image]

[Sample Project Image][2]

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArD7C.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tjjs.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Hz0.png)

Comment: better not to share a file but to post a sample set of data to show how your worksheet is structured and how the desired outcome looks like. This job sounds as simple as using this formula `=(Cell [MACRO PIVOT] - Cell [TSLA LAST])<=5` as the conditional formatting rule for cell **TSLA LAST**

Comment: Its giving me the "the syntax of this name isnt correct.

Comment: @Terry W answer works for me.  I assume you were using the literal format in G3: `=(G3-E3)<=5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your `LAST` column is in column B, and `MACRO PIVOT` column is in column G,

highlight cell `B3`, set up the following conditional formatting rule using a custom formula. Choose the desired colour if the condition is `TRUE`.

```
=($G3-$B3)<=5
```

Then use the **format painter** to apply the same format from `B3` to the rest of the cells in column B.

[image: Solution]

Comment: got it to work thank you :)! I may ask more questions if thats okay in the future

Comment: @LisandroCisneros, you are welcome and please mark my answer as the accepted solution (by clicking the tick sign) if you believe it has worked for you. For further questions related to this particular case, you can ask it here. For other conditional formatting questions, try them out yourself first, and post new questions showing what you have tried then someone will be able to help you out :)